# Laravel Logout after POST requests

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, request

I'm making a laravel app and I use lots of POST requests. Many of them look like this one:

```
var classElements = document.querySelectorAll("tr.ui-selected td.filename");
var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
for(var x = 0;x < classElements.length;x++){
    var result;
    result = classElements[x].innerHTML;
    $.ajax({
        async: true,                      
        method: 'POST',
        url: '../public/deletefile',
        data: { filename: result, "_token": csrf  },
        success: function(response) {
           $( "tr.ui-selected" ).remove(response);              
        }
    });
};
```

And after making let's say 100 post requests i'm getting `500 Internal Server Error` and laravel says `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:`. And here is the HTML for the variable csrf:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ URL::to('upload') }}" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFileUpload">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token" />
</form>
```

Could this be solved?

Comment: Please show us how you're printing the `csrf` value.

Comment: `var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();` Show us how you've created the HTML for this.

Comment: Updated my question, check it

Answer (score 1):

> And after making let's say **100** post requests i'm getting 500 Internal
>   Server Error

This is a known issue when you do concurrent ajax requests. 
I am not sure if it's fixed in `5.1 or 5.2` versions, because I had the same issue in `5.0` version.

Some had this issue, some didn't and weren't able to replicate it. The issue could be dependent on the environment.

You could try upgrading to the latest version.

[Race condition on session engine causing unexpected behavior on concurrent requests](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5416)

Comment: So there is no solution?

Comment: @Alex I think there is no clear solution for now (AFAIK), see if running `php artisan optimize --force` helps.